# Error al borrar cookie

Tags: javascript

Hola compis tengo un código el cual cuando cliqueo un botón se borran unas cookies, la cosa es que el primer codigo si que me borra la cookie **ProductoTodocoches** pero la cookie **PrecioCantidad** no me la borra. Gracias de ante mano.

Código

```
function  Botoneliminar(valor) {
                        document.cookie = "ProductoTodocoches"+valor+"=; max-age=0";
                        document.cookie = "PrecioCantidad"+valor+"=; max-age=0";

                        window.location="http://localhost/coches/cart.php";

                    }
```

Comment: estas reescribiendo la cookie  sin mantener el valor anterior , la segunda linea debe ser algo como `document.cookie += "PrecioCantidad"+valor+"=; max-age=0";`

Comment: de esta manera se me bloquea el código entero javascript... no se ya por dopnde cogerlo xD

Answer (score 2):

Hay bastantes funciones, podrías intentar con:

```js
document.cookie.split(";").forEach(function(c) { document.cookie = c.replace(/^ +/, "").replace(/=.*/, "=;expires=" + new Date().toUTCString() + ";path=/"); });
```

[Ref.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179355/clearing-all-cookies-with-javascript)

- Lo que se hace es poner una fecha de expiración igual o menor a la fecha actual.

En dado caso que busques algo más básico y entendible podrías extraer lo requerido del método:

```js
// split de cada cookie guardada
var cookie = document.cookie.split(';');

// en este ejemplo elimina todas las cookies por medio de un for
// Si sólo quiere hacerlo estático puede buscar su cookie (por medio de console.log(document.cookie)) y aplicar el "expires"
for (var i = 0; i < cookie.length; i++) {
    // Se substrae el nombre formateado de la cookie que se quiere eliminar
    var chip = cookie[i],
        entry = chip.split("="),
        name = entry[0];
    // ------------------------------------------- Aquí se setea el tiempo de muerte.
    document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
}
```